# как добавить header в запрос JWT

Tags: node.js, jwt

Имею запрос на авторизацию :

```
app.post('/signin', function(req, res) {
    User.findOne({
        username: req.body.username
    }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) throw err;

        if (!user) {
            res.status(401).send({success: false, msg: 'Authentication failed. User not found.'});
        } else {
            // check if password matches
            user.comparePassword(req.body.password, function (err, isMatch) {
                if (isMatch && !err) {
                    // if user is found and password is right create a token
                    var token = jwt.sign(user.toJSON(), 'nodeauthsecret');
                    // return the information including token as JSON
                    res.json({success: true, token: 'JWT ' + token});
                } else {
                    res.status(401).send({success: false, msg: 'Authentication failed. Wrong password.'});
                }
            });
        }
    }
    )
})
```

и защищенный запрос на получение списка постов:

```
app.get('/posts', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false}),(req, res) => {
    var token = getToken(req.headers);
    console.log(token);
    if (token) {
        Post.find({}, 'title description', function (error, posts) {
            if (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
            res.send({
                posts: posts
            })
        }).sort({_id: -1})
    }
    else {
            return res.status(403).send({success: false, msg:' Unauthorized.'});
       }
})
```

после авторизации программа не пропускает меня на эту страницу говоря что пользователь не авторизован.

как я понимаю нужно добавить в header ключ Authorization cо значением токена, так как в POSTMAN запрос проходит.

но как это сделать в коде?

Comment: полагаю вам нужно добавить заголовок `Authorization: Bearer <access_token>`. Я в NodeJS не спец, но если верить гуглу, то заголовки в запрос устанавливаются вот так: `req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer <access_token>');`

Comment: хотя погодите. вы тут случайно не серверный код показали? где тогда код, в котором вы пытаетесь отправить запросы на сервер, у которых не проходит авторизация?